# Func in dictionary, how does this code work? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, delegates, explain

I am quite new in C# and my professor gave me this code, can you explain how does it work? I am curious about all these "=>" operators, and what is going on in Dictionary.

```
            _operationFunction = new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, int>>
            {
                ["+"] = (fst, snd) => (fst + snd),
                ["-"] = (fst, snd) => (fst - snd),
                ["*"] = (fst, snd) => (fst * snd),
                ["/"] = (fst, snd) => (fst / snd)
            };
           _operators.Push(_operationFunction[op](num1, num2));

        Func<int, int, int> Operation(String input) => (x, y) =>
            (
                (input.Equals("+") ? x + y :
                    (input.Equals("*") ? x * y : int.MinValue)
                )
            );
        _operators.Push(Operation(op)(num1, num2));
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator

Comment: The `["+"]` defines a key value, and the part after the `=` is shorthand for a function that takes in two integers (`fst` and `snd`) and returns a third integer (`(fst + snd)`). So it's assigning an "add" function to the "+" key of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (as well as the other expressions, with `=>` )

```
(fst, snd) => (fst + snd)
```

is a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions).

The lambda expressions in the dictionary represent the arithmetical operations between integers. So for each of the four operations of addition (+), multiplication (*), subtraction (-) and division (/), a lambda expression is supplied that describes these operations.

When we write the following:

```
_operationFunction[op](num1, num2)
```

the value of the dictionary associated with the key `op` is fetched and then the returned function (value) is applied for the integers `num1` and `num2`.

So if the value of `op` is the string `"+"`, then `_operationFunction[op]` returns a reference to the delegate essentially that is described by the lambda expression:

```
(fst, snd) => (fst + snd)
```

Then the "function" that this reference points to is applied for the arguments `num1` and `num2`.

You can read at [Func<T1,T2,TResult>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3?view=netcore-3.1) more regrading this that is used in your code.